# Wordpress Send User's Password

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function which should let people to by email their password by typing their registered email address. But for some reasons wordpress doesn't send any emails or showing any error for example if email not recognised in the user database:

```
 function wp_user_password($user_id) {

     function get_userdata($user_id) {
         return get_user_by('email', $_REQUEST['email']);
     }

     $user = get_userdata($user_id);

     $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

     $message = sprintf(__('Your registration details:'), $blogname)."\r\n\r\n";
     $message. = sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user - > user_email)."\r\n";
     $message. = sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass)."\r\n";

     @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('Requested Registration Details'), $blogname), $message);

     if (empty($plaintext_pass)) return;

     $message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user - > user_login)."\r\n";
     $message. = sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass)."\r\n";

     wp_mail($user - > user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
 }
 $this - > output(1, 'Email sent successfully');
```

I would really appreciate if you can help me with amending the code above. Many thanks.

Comment: This is not a good solution. *plaintext password* is very insecure. If a user forgets his password, the process should be to create a completely new password for the user, not to send the old password. It should be stored in a non-recoverable state, like hashed with salt.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the goal you are trying to achieve here of sending user their existing password is not doable.

Wordpress encrypts the passwords for every user when a user is registered and stores it in database. The encryption is one way and thus the password can never be recovered.

Problems with your code:

~ What is the use of $user_id here ?

```
function get_userdata($user_id) {
   return get_user_by('email', $_REQUEST['email']);
}
```

~ $plaintext_pass is uninitialized, so below statement will always be true

```
if (empty($plaintext_pass)) return;
```

If you are trying to create Forget password functionality, then you can use the existing wordpress functionality for it. This might be helpfull [WP_LOSTPASSWORD_URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_lostpassword_url)